# npm install is throwing up errors

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I needed node_modules so I did sudo npm install. I am getting this error.
[This is the error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIHdD.png)
I also tried installing it from root. It is still showing errors.

Node version is 8.14.0.
Npm version is 6.4.1.

Comment: Add your code snipet here instead of attaching image.

Answer (score 0):

Your node dependency has some specific build logic that depends on your system having what is known as "build essentials" - basic tools for compiling code. You should be able to gem them by typing in the Terminal `sudo apt-get install build-essential` and then press key <kbd>TAB</kbd> instead of pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Comment: I did that and the previous error is gone but now I am getting this new error .

Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/home/agile/Desktop/a/timetracker/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'